# Half burnt out LED tube lights in LED-mirror panel

Tags: electrical, led, light

Recently I moved into a new flat in the dorm and faced a problem with LED-mirror-panel in the bathroom and asked the landlord to fix the problem. Despite the responsible maintenance electric company came and took out the panel and fixed the problem and installed it on 03.02.2021, after 24hrs again, I faced the same problem. The LED set in a border of mirror panel hasn't worked fully. As you can see, just the left side is working:

[image: img]

Other electrical information can help to resolve the problem is the following:
The bathroom lighting has one *Ceiling-bulb*, and *LED-mirror-panel* on the wall. Both can switch on/off via double-switch as you can see in the picture.
[image: img]

I already checked [this](https://www.ledlightbulb.net/Projectengineering/how_to_repair_led_fluorescent_la.htm) and could be **power supply problem** in LED-mirror-panel, and this [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/129978/129758). This [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/70026/129758) that addressed to LED characteristics encouraged me to be patient to see the right side of the LED-mirror-panel could work one day.

Any help reflecting issue to the landlord or the responsible maintenance electric company will be highly appreciated.

**Update:** I realized that my next-door neighbour has also the same problem. Could be a *faulty phase* problem?

Comment: It's a problem with the product or the installation. Since you don't own the place, it's A) your responsibility to _report_ it, not _fix_ it, and B) probably illegal for you to do electrical work there anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Stop chasing the problem.  It is not yours to fix. It's a 100% waste of your time to try to fix it.

### Simply report it again.

And this is where people go wrong.  They say "But I reported it before and they DIDN'T FIX IT therefore they are totally incompetent and I should never call them again!"

That completely misunderstands *how troubleshooting works*... especially when the troubleshooting is at someone else's premises where you can't just hang out for a day to see if that fixed it.  The simple fact is that *technicians don't know*.  The best anyone can do is make a best guess, try something, see what happens, amend their guess, and try again.  This is called *iteration*.

The "best guesses" are often codified on a troubleshooting flowchart from the vendor.  (or simply from experience/common sense).   Often, "whether this has succeeded" is not immediately evident; time must pass to expose whether the fix has held.  This is normal.

Happens all the time where people have a problem that will be uncovered on step E of the troubleshooting flowchart. However they keep **firing the techs for incompetence** when they've only reached step B or C.  Some people will spend thousands of dollars at this.

So report the problem again so the technician knows that *the last thing* didn't work.  Now, they will try the next step on the troubleshooting flowchart.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I would do the same, but since I noticed that some neighbors in the building have this problem and It hasn't been fixed yet. So I'm looking for possible **technical** reasons since I'm Electrical Eng. Please check the update in my post.

Comment: @Mario I don't see much you could do, maybe identify the LED driver module and find a source for compatible replacements if they would be swappable, but that's 10% tech 90% shopping lol.